# Need help identifying a fantasy short story about a woman turning into a cat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a young woman turning into a cat. I read it (in German) about twenty years ago. It was published in a collection of cat stories; I remember Poe's 'The Black Cat' being among them.

- Her unhappy relationship with a man is an big part of the story. He is either about to leave her for another woman, or emotionally neglects her, or is oblivious to her love; I can't remember which. Anyway, the guy and his neglect/ abandonment/ obliviousness are the catalyst for her transformation into a cat.
- The woman first develops an aversion to water, making cleaning herself a complicated chore. Her behaviour also becomes more catlike in other ways. However, there are no physical changes until the very end, when she runs away because of something the guy does, starts feeling strange and disappears into the night.
- The guy searches for her but can't find her and is desperate. After a few days he finds a beautiful cat — the former woman — near his home. He takes the cat into his home and keeps her. The story ends with him offering milk first — which the cat refuses — and finest cream afterwards.
- There's a strong vibe that this is a happy ending — with her being more independent and less needy of his affection in her feline form, and with him finally being able to express warmth/love towards her.

Comment: I think I've read this, but I can't remember where. May have been in an *Ellery Queen* magazine or one of the many *Alfred Hitchcock*   anthologies.

Comment: The title had me think "A Witch's Curse" by Paul Ernst (1929) was the story you are looking for; then I read your description and I had to change my mind: it is not. Anyhow, this story might help you find the other one so I'll add it here.

Comment: Are you sure it was a cat? The outline is reminscent of Mrs Fox - by Sarah Hall (who was short listed for an Arthur C Clarke award for a different story). But (obviously) she turns into a fox and not a cat. Mrs Fox has been in a number of anthologies.

https://savidgereads.wordpress.com/2014/07/01/mrs-fox-sarah-hall/

Mrs Fox is losely based (aparently - I've only read Mrs Fox) on Lady-into-Fox
https://savidgereads.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/lady-into-fox-david-garnett/

Comment: I have been looking for this as well. My Dad had an old record album with the story on it that I used to listen to when I was younger, about 40 years ago. I would do anything to find the album. We haven't been able to track his down, but would love to find it again. There's one out there somewhere, just not sure where :(

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151008/story-about-a-murderous-cat-woman-and-her-husband/151081?r=SearchResults#151081, I.e. "Cat Wife" although that's a radio play.