# Story about a murderous cat-woman and her husband

Tags: short-stories, story-identification, audio-book

Long ago, I recall hearing an audio story, likely on cassette, about a man and his wife. He wants to prove himself to her and eventually ends up pushing another man down the stairs, to her satisfaction. For reasons I cannot remember, she begins turning into a cat (maybe figuratively?). This story has been a little burr in brain for ages, and I have been completely unable to find any info on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds a lot like [*Cat Wife,*](http://www.oldtimeradiodownloads.com/thriller/lights-out/cat-wife-1938-03-30) written by Arch Obeler and performed by Wyllis Cooper's [*Lights Out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(radio_show)) radio program in February, 1939.

From the Old Time Radio link:

> A husband's feline-like wife goes too far. This broadcast has an amazing performance by Boris Karloff and an even better one by the actress who stars as "Cat Wife" -- sadly she receives no billing. When Linda arrives home with her friends making a rabble of a noise an argument ensues with her husband accusing her and her friends of behaving like a pack of yowling, screaming ally cats and he announces he's through with her. Then she cruelly informs him that she only married him for his money. He accuses her of being a cat, a big white heartless cat, with unexpected consequences...

It was a fan favorite of the *Lights Out* radio series and has been issued on various media.

Comment: Boris Karloff had an amazing voice, even if he's most famous for a playing a character that only grunts.

Comment: The last sentence of the quotation has an extra "a cat" I think. Also, "heatless" or "heartless"? I presume either could work in this case!

Comment: Or maybe "a cat, a big white heartless cat"

Comment: And indeed, listening to the audio, he says that line, "a cat, a big white heartless cat". That said, Joe is quoting the webpage, which has the very same error.

Comment: I didn't notice the error on the web page. I made the appropriate corrections.

Comment: He does kill three men for her, but as best I can tell, he shoots all three of them.

Comment: Definitely the one, thanks!  It sounds so much like I remember, though I seem to have gotten some details muddled over the years.  I'm going to pretend like it's actually "heatless," as that makes me chuckle.